# I could able to attach 2 NICS to the VM but Plan to add total 4 NICs to the linux VM using terraform azure

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

```
on .terraform\modules\fpm\main.tf line 27, in resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "main1":
  27:   network_interface_ids = [ "${var.nic1-id}", "${var.nic2-id}"]
    |----------------
    | var.nic1-id is tuple with 2 elements
    | var.nic2-id is tuple with 2 elements

Inappropriate value for attribute "network_interface_ids": element 0: string
required.
```

Comment: network_interface_ids = var.nic1-id
two nics are attached in the above way. But I need to add "var.nic2-id" as well. Please any one help in this issue.Thanks !!

Comment: Can you provide relevant part of your `main.tf`? Where and how do you use network_interface_ids and what are `var.nic1-id` and `var.nic2-id`?

Comment: I'm creating network interface using az-nic/main.tf separately and  getting output values here do passing as input variable as var.nic1-id and var.nic2-id in az-vm/main.tf

Comment: I mean actual example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute `network_interface_ids` expect a list of the network interface ids, so if you input all the NIC ids via the variables, then you can put them into a list for the attribute like this:

```
network_interface_ids = list(var.nic1-id, var.nic2-id)
```

But if the two variables are two lists, you need to merge them into one:

```
setunion(var.nic1-id, var.nic2-id)
```

Comment: Thank you so much  for the support above answer is working well Mr. Charles & Mr. Marcin

Comment: i need to attach nics to the VM frist with value getting from "var.nics-id" and need to go with var.nic2-id

Comment: but its getting attached to the VM with alphabetical order wise when I used :-
setunion(var.nic1-id, var.nic2-id)

Comment: so using this 
network_interface_ids=concat(var.nic1-id,var.nic2-id)

Comment: @Haridvpsk But if there are multiple same NICs, doesn't them conflict?